# ReadLinesAsync in UWP from absolute file path

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I get error

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)

My code is

```
public async void ReadFile()
    {     
        var path = @"F:\VS\WriteLines.xls";
        var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
        var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        foreach (var line in readFile.OrderBy(line =>
        {
            int lineNo;
            var success = int.TryParse(line.Split(';')[4], out lineNo);
            if (success) return lineNo;
            return int.MaxValue;
        }))
        {
            itemsControl.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

The error shows up at `var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);`

Comment: just to make sure, the path is correct and file exists.

Comment: Side note XLS is generally non-text format... So reading as lines of text would fail - but it is unlikely cause of error you see.

Comment: I have tried with .txt file too, and too it doesn't work. I stick to .xls because in plain console code it worked and I was able to list lines from the .xls successfuly.

Comment: Am I making some error in the way I provide the path? Nothing is underscored before build. Only when building the error comes up at the path.

Comment: The path and file format are ok. First of ako, you are using wrong api, second, your app probably does not have permission to aby file. Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions. Why do you need to read file from hardcoded url? Basically, in UWP the file must be either in app instalation folder, or app data folder or documents library, or you need to let user to choose the file, e.g. using file picker.

Comment: that's it. There is no need for full path url. I just use it as I didn't think of any other way. I guess that's it, I will place the file in app's folder and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read a file from an arbitrary location on disk in a UWP App.
There are a couple of ways you can still accomplish your task:

1. You can add the WriteLines.xls file to your project and set it's **build action** to **Content** and **Copy to output Directory** to **Copy if newer**. You can then access the file with the code you have by simply replacing the "path" value to:

`var path = @"WriteLines.xls"`

[More details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders)

2. If you need to be able to read any files from disk, you need to either use a FilePicker to select the file or copy the file in the Documents Folder and change the folder to:

`var folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;`

[More details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers)

Comment: The solution nr 1 has actualy got me going again. Thank You very much. I no more get errors and solution builds. I need to sort it out on XAML side as I still don't get it display my lines.

Comment: got it, I managed to display my .xls lines in <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /> on the xaml page. Thank you AlexDrenea for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for file with absolute path from application's local folder - hence it throws that error as you provide path that includes drive name.

In general UWP is very restrictive on where/how you can get files from - I don't think you can get it from absolute path in the sample (app needs more permissions to get to similar places). You can try [StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx).

Detailed info on locations app can access - [UWP apps on Windows 10: File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: He is asking about UWP, which is different from Win8. This link would be better: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: @Liero I could not find good link. Win8 RT is close, but indeed link you found is better than [Windows 8: The right way to Read & Write Files in WinRT](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html). I've edited it in to the post.