# UWP: Opening a specific file

Tags: uwp

After getting a tight understanding of file handling in UWP one point is still not clear for me:
I have an application that runs on Microsoft Surface 3 only so I can assume that an attached USB Drive always gets the Drive D:

Is there any possibility to open the file d:\FixedFolderName\FixedFilename.txt without using the FileOpen dialog for the user?

Background is that I have to transfer Data between the tablet and a PC and a USB drive is the only opportunity in my configuration. The folder names and filenames are always fixed so there is no need for the user to select them manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReadLinesAsync in UWP from absolute file path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661051/readlinesasync-in-uwp-from-absolute-file-path)

Answer (score 0):

You can get some files from the USB drives if you request the `Removable Storage` capability in the `package.appxmanifest`. But there are strict restrictions.

> [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) The removableStorage capability provides programmatic access to files
>   on removable storage, like USB keys and external hard drives, filtered
>   to the file-type associations declared in the package manifest. For
>   example, if a document-reader app declares a .doc file-type
>   association, it can open .doc files on the removable storage device,
>   but not other types of files. Be careful when you declare this
>   capability, because users may include a variety of info in their
>   removable storage devices, and will expect your app to provide a valid
>   justification for programmatic access to the removable storage for all
>   files of the declared type.
>
> Users will expect your app to handle any file associations that you
>   declare. So don't declare file associations that your app cannot
>   handle responsibly.

So you can use a custom file type like "mycfg", and you can access this files from the removable storage too.

Comment: That would do th ejob for *.mycfg, but what about *.jpg? Can I copy jpg to the removable storage, too?